# Is there any difference between "Object[] x" and "Object x[]"?

Tags: java, arrays, declaration

I was updating a legacy code base in Java and I found a line like this:

```
Object arg[] = { new Integer(20), new Integer(22) };
```

That line catched my attention because I am used to this kind of code:

```
Object[] arg = { new Integer(20), new Integer(22) };
```

The content of the array isn't important here. I'm curious about the brackets next to the variable name versus the brackets next to the class name. I tried in Eclipse (with Java 5) and both lines are valid for the compiler.

Is there any difference between those declarations?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Both are legal and both work. But placing [] before the array's name is recommended.

From [Javadocs](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html):

> You can also place the square brackets after the array's name:

```
float anArrayOfFloats[]; // this form is discouraged
```

> However, convention discourages this form; the brackets identify the array type and should appear with the type designation.

Comment: Putting the [] with the type is much clearer; try reading the "[]" as "array" - int[] reads as "int array", while int variableName[] sort of tacks the "array" part on as an afterthought.

Answer (score 14):

No, they both work. But watch out:

```
float anArrayOfFloats[], aSecondVariable;
```

will declare one array of floats and one float, while:

```
float[] anArrayOfFloats, aSecondVariable;
```

will declare *two* arrays of floats.

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference. Both are legal.

You can read in Java Language Specification http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/arrays.doc.html

> The [] may appear as part of the type
>   at the beginning of the declaration,
>   or as part of the declarator for a
>   particular variable, or both, as in
>   this example:
>
> ```
> byte[] rowvector, colvector, matrix[];
> ```

Comment: The matrix one is particularly evil.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another good reason to write `Integer[] ints` instead of `Integer ints[]` is because of inheritance relations: `Integer[]` is subtype of `Number[]` is subtype of `Object[]`.

In other words, you can put `Integers` in an `Object` array, so you can think of the `[]` as part of the object's type definition -- which is why it makes sense to have it close to the type instead of the object name.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.